# Google Pub/Sub retry policy ? how to deal with a poison pill?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

In a Pub/Sub 'push' model the docs say this:

If the push endpoint returns an error code, messages are retried for up to 7 days with an exponential backoff policy (capped at 10 seconds).

Is there a way to decide what to do with the message after the retry period ? i.e. send it to some error queue etc ?

Answer (score 1):

The seven-day retry period represents the maximum amount of time unacknowledged messages are retrained in Cloud Pub/Sub to be delivered to subscribers. After the seven days pass, a message is automatically deleted from Cloud Pub/Sub and no longer delivered. The system does not currently support performing any actions on these deleted messages such as sending them to an error queue.